# Simple data analysis with Pandas - how to remove repetitive code

Tags: pandas

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

dfboth = {
        'I': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'S': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'], 
        'DVAR': [800, 300, 820, 330, 910, 350], 
        'CVAR': [1001, 612, 990, 639, 600, 130]}

dfboth = pd.DataFrame(dfboth)
dfboth = dfboth.assign(DVARCHANGE=dfboth['DVAR'].diff(2))
dfboth = dfboth.assign(CVARCHANGE=dfboth['CVAR'].diff(2))

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (24, 9) # (w, h)

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot('I','DVAR', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="X"])
plt.plot('I','DVARCHANGE', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="X"])
plt.title("X-D")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot('I','DVAR', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="Y"])
plt.plot('I','DVARCHANGE', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="Y"])
plt.title("Y-D")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot('I','CVAR', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="X"])
plt.plot('I','CVARCHANGE', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="X"])

plt.title("X-C")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot('I','CVAR', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="Y"])
plt.plot('I','CVARCHANGE', data=dfboth[dfboth.S=="Y"])
plt.title("Y-C")

plt.legend()
```

I have a series of data points (a time series), I=1,2,3 ... and they each pertain to a certain 'S', in this example, X and Y. For each reading, we have two variables DVAR and CVAR. I am trying to make this graph [image: like this one]

I compare for S X and Y, DVAR and it's change from the previous reading, and CVAR and it's change in previous reading.

You can also see annoying repetition. But I actually have 12 S's not just X and Y. And I have more variables.

I believe there's a much better way of doing this than I have written using either stacked indexes or some kind of pivot table. But I've not been able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for`-loop:

```
plot_titles = ["X-D", "Y-D", "X-C", "Y-C"]
y1 = ['DVAR', 'DVAR', 'CVAR', 'CVAR']
y2 = [y + 'CHANGE' for y in y1]
data1 = ["X", "Y", "X", "Y"]

for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    plt.plot('I', y1[i], data = dfboth[dfboth.S == data1[i]])
    plt.plot('I', y2[i], data = dfboth[dfboth.S == data1[i]])
    plt.title(plot_titles[i])
    plt.legend()
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of something like that, but I thought there was something even more idiomatic pandas that I could do... I  dont know for some reason I try to to do everything in pandas language and declarative not procedural...

Comment: Also that doesn't quite work because you don't have the dfboth = dfboth.assign(DVARCHANGE=dfboth['DVAR'].diff(2))
dfboth = dfboth.assign(CVARCHANGE=dfboth['CVAR'].diff(2))
 logic

Comment: Agreed, it would be nice to have a Pandas' way of doing this. I can't think of one now, so I'm hoping someone else will answer.